# Particles don't collide with collision object?

Tags: particles, physics

I have an object with a Mirror, Subsurface, and Solidify modifier.

I gave it *Collision* in the Physics panel, but the particle system just goes through the object. I have not baked the particles before.

I tried adding a new object without any modifiers and the collision works. Does collision of the particle can be done in original object, or any something wrong with my scene?

I just wanna to make this:

[image]

This is what is happening
[image: Collision example]

And my particle setting
[image: Particle setting]

Comment: The collision physics should take all the modifiers before it into account.. Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Answer (score 2):

You could add small slices to a plane as emitter vertex group.

[image]

Add a wind force field to blow the particles up

Compare the results of the *Kill Particles* checkbox from the settings of your collision object. When you don't kill them they will be deflected. Make sure the particles cannot escape through holes in your model.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[.blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/32395)

Answer (score 0):

Why not make your particles follow a path?  If your car needs to actually be moving, parent the emitter and paths. I recall I did something similar before and it worked well.

Comment: No, my car not moving, i just want to make something like aerodynamics machine, just wondering with aerodynamic of my car modeling bad or good :D

Comment: but thank you for the answer guys :D
I visit this site everyday, and really help me be a pro :D
Sorry for my bad english, im from Indonesia, nice to meet you :D

Comment: Or for a more natural flowy effect you could use wind forces.

Comment: I've been find the answer, because my object collision and the particle isn't in one layer

Comment: Vince Scalia : yup, i'll try it. Thank you :D